# app.get() third parameter in Node.js with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am working through an excellent tutorial on using the Node.js package Passport ([link](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)) for user authentication, and I ran into a piece of code that I really don't understand:

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});
```

My question is with the `isLoggedIn` parameter. I looked at the official site, and did some google searches, but nowhere does it say that you can pass three parameters into `app.get`. I've only ever seen two. What is this third (optional, I assume) parameter?

I'm not asking about the `isLoggedIn` itself, but rather, about the fact that it's a third parameter I've never seen passed into `app.get()` before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called middleware, and it's called before the third parameter (the callback).

Middleware functions examples: access checks, check to see if user is logged in before passing resources, and such.

Comment: What does the middleware parameter expect in return? Any value, or some particular one, like bool or object?

Comment: There's no built-in data type expected.  You can build your own middleware to return objects, bools, strings, etc. Middleware isn't restricted to just one middleware function call, either.  You can have multiple middleware calls. Whatever that middleware returns can be used by the callback function (the third parameter).

Answer (score 5):

It's in the express documentation: http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.get

The syntax is:
`app.get(path, callback [, callback ...])`
i.e.
`app.get(path, ...callback)`

The syntax includes taking in a path as the first parameter, followed by as many middleware (having access to the request and response) callback functions as you desire. It's not limited to one. They are asynchronous and chained together by calling the next() parameter.

```
function callbackOne(req, res, next) {
    //some code
    next();
}
function callbackTwo(req, res, next) {
    //some code
    res.render();
}
app.get(path, callbackOne, callbackTwo)
```

So, in your case, the isLoggedIn parameter is simply just another middleware function that eventually calls next() if the user is logged in to bring execution to the third parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved this question a few years ago :) I wonder how you even found it? Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Thanks :) Cool. I figured but wanted to write out a detailed explanation for those who may stumble upon the question. I've been in the habit of reading through all of the docs of important frameworks at least once. It's proving to be EXTREMELY helpful.