# I don't understand the syntax of the following javaScript code

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
else{
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
    res.redirect("/secrets");
    });
}
```

Why is there no "." after authenticate("local") (here)and before (req, res, function () .........)

Comment: It's a function call. The function call returns another function, and the code calls that function also.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: `passport.authenticate` looks something like this `passport.authenticate = (type) => { .... return (req, res, callback) => { .... callback() } }`

Answer (score 2):

[`passport.authenticate`](https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/middleware/) returns a function. That returned function can then be called (like any function) - `req`, `res`, and another callback function are arguments that can be passed.

If you're finding it difficult to read, it might make more sense to break the returned function out into its own identifier.

```
const passportHandler = passport.authenticate("local");
passportHandler(req, res, function () {
  res.redirect("/secrets");
});
```

Often, an even better approach would be to for the Passport middleware to be declared for the route itself, instead of declaring both a route callback and then passing down the `req` and `res` again. That is

```
app.post(
  'someEndpoint',
  passport.authenticate("local"),
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/secrets");
  }
)
```

if you can figure out a way around the `else`. `passport.authenticate` returns a route handler callback, and the `(req, res) =>` [is also a route handler callback.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726786/app-get-third-parameter-in-node-js-with-express).